# Can't get a XMLHttpRequest's response neither from local file:/// nor from local web server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to develop a small RSS reader that will fetch the XML documents from various websites.
I thought that XHR would be simple, if a user can manipulate the browser UI to fetch an obviously "Cross Origin" web page, shouldn't JavaScript code be able to do so as easily? apparently no :/

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // A real feed URL, its web server should allow CORS
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://feeds2.feedburner.com/thenextweb');
    xhr.send();
```

Locally opening my HTML page (file:///) makes the Origin null and the response empty, but if i access the page trough a local web server (i tried Python and Node server scripts), the Origin is not null but the response is still empty.

I know there are enough XHR questions around, but can someone point out what am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

Feedburner does not support CORS (yet). These are the headers I receive from feedburner when executing your code from jsfiddle:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
ETag: ckkcnAejDTcF+4d0Kj6kftZuq+0
Last-Modified: Tue, 30 Jul 2013 19:56:16 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 30 Jul 2013 19:58:11 GMT
Expires: Tue, 30 Jul 2013 19:58:11 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
```

If it supported CORS you should see an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in there

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In that case, do you have examples of RSS feeds that support CORS? i tried various other popular feeds but neither give the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. I'm not sure if CORS is a rare thing or if i am interneting wrongly.

Comment: I think you can use JSONP through Google Feed API to get most of what you are looking for: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=The%20Next%20Web&callback=processResults`. The API is documented here: https://developers.google.com/feed/